# Do I need to use a auto-generated column as primary key, when I have a UUID from authorization server?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am writing a resource server based on OAuth2 structure. I have a table `user`, and I will be storing the `sub` claim of JWT response into that table as a unique key for other table to reference it. I tried to do this in order to avoid checking the database for each incoming request.

If that key(`sso_id`) is already unique, do I still need to have a `id` key that will be generated automatically? Is there any performance gain/loss for omitting that key?

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "user";
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    sso_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to generate a different Primary Key. A primary must meet 2 requirements, nothing else. It must not be null or partially null, and it must be unique within the table. As long as it meets those requirements, it is valid. Some would argue that you *should* generate a PK (has some validity), but that is a philosophical argument a specified requirement. You could actually use the value passed as the PK, and perhaps even a FK. I am torn between assuming that you single sign-on (sso_id) and the passed jwt_id are the same or not. Why would you define it as 100 characters, which is much larger than required if they were, but it also seems logical that they would be. I will assume they are not. Also I assume that reference to originating table is available. With that then the following would be perfectly valid.

```
create table "user" (
       jwt_id uuid  
     , sso_id varchar(100) not null unique
     , constraint user_pk 
                  primary_key(jwt_id)
     , constraint user_2_jwt_fk
                  foreign key (jwt_id) 
                  references jwt(jwt_id) 
);
```

Comment: You are right. I have a typo for `jwt_id`. They should be the same and they are `sso_id`, and yes I guess the characters I need is only 36. But it is good to know that what I am doing is actually ok.

Comment: It is good. But Postgres supports [UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-uuid.html) as a native data type and required only 16 bytes storage. I would recommend using UUID as the data type.

Comment: thank you so much. I think this is a really good recommendation and I should have used it in the first place. thanks!